# Elementary OS calling home?

Tags: security, privacy, elementaryos

I was having a bit of a problem with the power that feeds my modem here. So, while I was solving the problem it disconnected the internet access.

And the following screen popped up on the screen:

[image]

Then, after it reconnected, and I clicked "Try again" in order to see if I could made sense of it, it's fast enough in majority of times to let me take a better screenshot, but on the right top part of screen, there's more than just the logo on the left, like, Support and Get Involved buttons:

[image]

Is Elementary OS for some reason always talking to their network? If you don't know the answer but is knowleageable enough to guide me on how to find out can you do this? I appreciate any answers and ideias.

Also, the only info online I have found about it is here but no actual answer: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1524427

Comment: At [su], we use on-site Imgur hosting. Also, please don't use URL shorteners.

Comment: It's probably part of a system that detects captive portals.

Comment: Thanks for the revisions and info @DanielB! About the urls a message saying I couldn't yet include more than one or two links appeared and I couldn't post because of this. So I used the workaround... But now I know!

Comment: About captive portals @DanielB can you tell me why an OS should have them for? Also, how do I find its config on the system and change it if I so want to?

Comment: The OS doesn’t have them. (Free) wifi hotspots do. All modern operating systems attempt to detect captive portals.

Comment: Yeah, after I wrote the comment and also read again yours I thought of this! But anyway, this is my own modem, I mean, the one the ISP provided me... As far as I know there's nothing like this on it. This never happened on any other OS before...

Comment: In most cases, ISP provided modems will show a web page (containing troubleshooting information and so on), if they can't establish a connection to the ISP. Elementary detects this as a captive portal (since your router / modem is redirecting all connections), and opens the page for you to see it. If the modem has connected by that time, the redirect no longer happens, and you are taken to the ElementaryOS website instead. So no, no "phoning home" as such, just the OS trying to be helpful. (FYI, all other major OSes do the same thing).

Comment: I appreciate your explanation @JonasCz The question came out as I never experienced something like this before. And this windows that pops up: I don't even know which software it is related to if any, because it is not a browser. But all right. I get it :) But if possible would be nice to understand how it works at system levels and all, but for that my knowledge on the system should be greater than at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

On elementary OS, the browser is called as part of a network script started on boot at /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/90captive_portal_test

That script in turns calls the binary file /usr/bin/captive-login and both files are part of the 'capnet-assist' package.  I don't like this sort of 'calling home' either, and I disabled captive-login by removing its executable bits and making it immutable, so it won't be overwritten on updates.

The command 'strings /usr/bin/captive-login' will give you some clues about what the binary is doing.

Comment: Comments to the effect that "all other major OSes do the same thing" are demonstrably false. The "capnet-assist" package is execrable, and so is the whole idea behind it. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/604863/how-do-i-purge-pantheon-desktop-why-does-this-window-appear